# How can I use this jQuery image zoom plugin with jQuery image sliders?

Tags: jquery, slider, zooming

So I have got this great plugin , that zooms through images with a lens effect. Uptill now it is working for single images but what I want is to apply the zoom effect on images that are in my jQuery slider. 
I have added this div in to my image slider but when I click on image it takes me to another tab which just display me the image. 
I want to get the image zoom on mouse hover effect in all images of sliders.
Here  you can find what I have just got working on :
[Demo here](http://zoomy.me/home)

My slider HTML:

```
<div class="pikachoose">


<ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">

    <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img class="zoom" src="images/slide/1.jpg"/></a><span>This is an example of the basic theme.</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img class="zoom" src="images/slide/2.jpg"/></a>
<span>jCarousel is supported and can be integrated with PikaChoose!</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Image Zoom HTML:
   `<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="images/slide/2.jpg" class="zoom" ><img src="images/slide/2.jpg" /></a>
    </div>`

Javascript for both:

```
<script> // zoom Jquery
$(function(){
    $('.zoom').zoomy({border:'6px solid #fff'});
});




</script>


        <script language="javascript">     //Slider Jquery
        $(document).ready(
            function (){
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true,carouselOptions:{wrap:'circular'}});
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you have to use the callback "animationFinished" on pikachoose

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? At exactly where I need to call this function. I will appreciate if you can give code example.

Comment: Give me some minutes, it is first time when i play with them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your html should looks like :

```
<div class="pikachoose">
    <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
        <li><a href="images/slide/big1.jpg">
            <img src="images/slide/1.jpg"/></a><span>This is an example of the basic theme.</span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="images/slide/big2.jpg">
            <img src="images/slide/2.jpg"/></a><span>jCarousel is supported and can be integrated with PikaChoose!</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Actually you need to follow just some basic stuff, according to [zoomy usage](http://zoomy.me/usage) . You can put classes and everything, but the wrapper of the image ( that `<a>` inside `<li>` ) must have as href the location of big image.

To have a working zoomy on slider you need to call it each time after the slider transition is done

```
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose({
                    carousel:true,
                    carouselOptions:{wrap:'circular'},
                    animationFinished : function( e ){
                        e.anchor.zoomy();
                    }
                });
```

Notice the "animationFinished" option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The magnifier icon now comes inside slider :)
But there is one little issue, I wanted my slider to be in landscape mode as it gives cool look. but unfortunately the zoom effects works only if the images are shown smaller as compared to their original size:/...

Comment: I did not understand your question. The image from "href" should be much bigger than the image from "img".